# show value on the dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I'am creating a dialog box dynamically.I want to print the dynamic value which i receive as a response from the spring controller on the dialog box.
As $(document).ready(function () loads first i could not able to show dynamic value on the dialog box.

Below is the code i tried:

```
    var $dialog; 
var dynamicValue;
    var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $dialog = $('<div></div>')
           .html('<table><tr><td>' + dynamicValue + '</td></tr></table>')
          .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width:"400",
            height:300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });


    function showDialog()
    {
        var xmlHttp;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var url = contextPath+"/aboutATM.htm";
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            handleServerResponse(xmlHttp);
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);

        function handleServerResponse(xmlHttp)
        {   
           if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
           {
             $dialog.dialog('open');
             $dialog.dialog("option", "title", "Loading....").dialog("open"); 
          dynamicValue = xmlHttp.responseText;
           }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: call the function showDialog()  at the end of the doc ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified a little. It will work for you..

```
 var $dialog; 
 var dynamicValue;
    var contextPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $dialog = $('<div></div>')
          .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width:"400",
            height:300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });


    function showDialog()
    {
        var xmlHttp;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var url = contextPath+"/aboutATM.htm";
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            handleServerResponse(xmlHttp);
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);

        function handleServerResponse(xmlHttp)
        {   
           if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
           {
             $dialog.dialog('open');
             $dialog.dialog("option", "title", "Loading....").dialog("open"); 
             $dialog.html('<table><tr><td>' + xmlHttp.responseText + '</td></tr></table>')
           }   
        }
    }
```